# For loop not working in expect sript

Tags: unix, expect

I have written an expect script to login into another server using ssh. But, when I want to do the same for multiple servers using a for loop, it doesnt work.
Below is the script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    match_max 5000
set expect_out(buffer) {}

for i in `cat node_list.txt`
do

node_ip=`echo $i| awk -F"," '{print $1}'`
node_initial_pwd=`echo $i| awk -F"," '{print $2}'`

spawn ssh root@$node_ip

expect {
"*(yes/no)?" {send "yes\r";exp_continue}
"'s password:" {send "$node_initial_pwd\r";exp_continue}
"*current*" {send "$node_initial_pwd\r";exp_continue}
"Enter*" {send "Jan2016!\r";exp_continue}
"Retype*" {send "Jan2016!\r";exp_continue}
"\\\$" { puts "matched prompt"}
}

done
```

node_list.txt has IP's and passwords separated by a comma(,).

Error I get is this:

```
mayankp@mayankp:~/scripts/new$ ./connect-to-server.sh
invalid command name "i"
while executing
"i"
("for" initial command)
invoked from within
"for i in `cat node_list.txt`"
(file "./connect-to-server.sh" line 6)
```

Can you please help me in achieving this? I know I am mixing up bash and expect here, but I have no clue how to run for loop in expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you are mixing up shell and Expect syntax here.  Expect is based on Tcl, documentation of the generic language commands can be found at http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/contents.htm .

A rough untested translation of the loop you are trying to write is

```
set inputchannel [open node_list.txt]

while {[gets $inputchannel line] != -1} {
    set fields [split $line ,]
    set node_ip [lindex $fields 0]
    set node_initial_pwd [lindex $fields 1]

    spawn ssh root@$node_ip

    ...etc...
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. The only problem I see is if the password contains a comma, then the variable only contains a portion of the password. To fight this: `set passwd [join [lassign [split $line ,] name] ,]` or `regexp {^(.*?),(.*)$} $line -> name passwd`